# Quick grey background when click on layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

I can see in some android application a quick grey background appearing and disappearing when clicking on a layout.
How can i do that for a switch with a text when i click on "the line" of the switch(i guess i have to add something in the xml of the switch)?

Comment: can you provide an image for example of what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use selectableItemBackground in background of view

```
  <Button
     android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="45dp"
     android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
     android:text="UPDATE EMAIL"
     android:padding="10dp"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:textColor="@color/white"
     android:textSize="16dp"
     android:id="@+id/btnContinue"/>
```

If your view has own color then you should use ?selectableItemBackground as forground color like below:

```
  <Button
     android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="45dp"
     android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
     android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
     android:text="UPDATE EMAIL"
     android:padding="10dp"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:textColor="@color/white"
     android:textSize="16dp"
     android:id="@+id/btnContinue"/>
```

Comment: I tried, but only the switch has this grey background whereas i want the whole line

Comment: please share the screenshot for the better understanding.

Comment: My bad! Actually with foreground it worked like a charm!